# Translating month number into month name

Tags: performance, php, datetime, comparative-review

Time is very important from times immemorial. Doing great things and making it happen in less time is more important as it can mean less effort. So I really like to know which way is faster and more efficient in the following codes, and I would happy to know any other way we can achieve the same code:

```
$month=date('m');
//Using If..else
 if($month==1){
    echo "January";
}elseif($month==2){
    echo "February";
}elseif($month==3){
    echo "March";
}elseif($month==4){
    echo "April";
}elseif($month==5){
    echo "May";
}elseif($month==6){
    echo "June";
}elseif($month==7){
    echo "July";
}elseif($month==8){
    echo "August";
}elseif($month==9){
    echo "September";
}elseif($month==10){
    echo "October";
}elseif($month==11){
    echo "November";
}else{
    echo "December";
}
```

```
//Using Switch
switch($month){
case 1:
    echo "January";
break;
case 2:
    echo "February";
break;
case 3:
    echo "March";
break;
case 4:
    echo "April";
break;
case 5:
    echo "May";
break;
case 6:
    echo "June";
break;
case 7:
    echo "July";
break;
case 8:
    echo "August";
break;
case 9:
    echo "September";
break;
case 10:
    echo "October";
break;
case 11:
    echo "November";
break;
default:
    echo "December";
break;
}
```

```
//Using Array
$month_s=array(1=>"January",2=>"February",3=>"March",4=>"April",5=>"May",6=>"June",
7=>"July",8=>"August",9=>"September",10=>"October",11=>"November",12=>"December");
echo isset($month_s[$month]) ? $month_s[$month] : '';
```

Comment: write a script, use `$start = microtime(true)` and then `microtime(true) - $start` to get a rough idea of the time each approach takes, and you have your answer. Do try with a larger array, too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like I said in my comment: If you want to know which is faster, write a benchmarking script, it's *that* easy:

```
$start = microtime(true);
//if-hell approach
$ifs = microtime(true) - $start;
$start = microtime(true);
//switch
$switch = microtime(true) - $start;
$start = microtime(true);
//array
$array = microtime(true) - $start;
```

Then compare and echo the results in any way you like.
My gut tells me that in this case, the `switch` will probably be the faster option. Considering a switch construction is sort of like labeling blocks of code, and then do some sort of eval-go-to thingy.
Branching (`if`) is faster in terms of compilation, perhaps, but for the month of december, you'll end up performing *all* if statements.
The array approach, for this example, doesn't look like the fastest approach you can take in this case, because it's constructing an array, performing a HashTable lookup, evaluate the result of that lookup, then *perform the same lookup again*, or return an empty string. HashTable lookups are as fast as it gets, of course, but still, you're having to do 2 of them, just *after you've constructed the HashTable*. The other approaches don't construct to *then* perform a lookup.

Mind you, This is micro-optimization of the worst kind. It's completely pointless and the speed difference won't be noticeable. Especially if you use some form of OP-Code caching (APC, for example). That should be the first port of call if you're trying to optimize some code.

*What code should you use?:*
This is the better question to ask. The efficiency of some snippet of code isn't just determined by the time it takes to execute. Efficient code is good code (is stable, performant, error and notice-free) and is ***easy to read, update and maintain***.
If your determining the name of the month then it's pretty obvious the data-set is limited to 12 valid strings. But in most cases, you might end up with an ever growing `switch` or `if-elseif-else` tree. That's *not* efficient coding. The moment you have to scroll to see a single block of code, you can safely say it's time to think about refactoring your code.

That's why I'd either use the array approach (works just as well when data is coming from a query, so you can create a function that you can reuse). Or, if you *are* working on dates, I'd give way to *normalization*, and use [the `DateTime` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). when I see `new DateTime` or `$d = DateTime::createFromFormat`, I know what to exepct. Even more so when I see:

```
[public] function doStuff(DateTime $date)
{
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I used to think that good codes use less time and effort. The code I provided is just an example. So do I prefer Array. My experience in php is just 11 months old. Does it mean putting codes into functions or objects when you said about 'codes refactoring'?

Comment: @MawiaHL: the term _"refactoring code"_ can mean a variety of things: A new version of PHP is deployed and some extension (like `mysql_*`) are deprecated, the process of removing all calls to that extension is _refactoring the code_. If some intern wrote a script that doesn't match the coding standards you uphold, that script has to be normalized, in doing so, you tend to optimize some sections of that script, this, too, is refactoring. If you've got some code, and want to make it OO, then you'll have to refactor it, too, but in that case, I'd rather call it a rewrite :)

Comment: A look up array OR a list would be the most efficient way of doing it.  I'm tending towards the list more than array tbh though I think that's just personal habit

Comment: @Dave: A PHP array is what you'd call a list or vector in most other languages. Even so: the lookup will be fast, but you have to take the constructing of that list into account, too. Either way, I'd use an array for this, too: it's the more scalable/maintainable approach for something like this. When the choice is between an ever growing switch or an array, go with the A-team :)

Comment: @elias in most other languages array is not the same as list<T> adding/removing/resizing arrays is typically expensive in language terms lists not so much so.  Although they look/behave similar to the end user they're distinctly different.  However in this instance either would be just fine the discussions of list vs array are for a different time

Comment: @Dave: Granted. I was referring to, what is called an array in PHP would be a List in languages such as Java (eg an array of objects). An array of zend objects needn't be stored as a contiguous block in memory, yet it'll use an array of pointers instead. It's just one of those internal things you don't (need?) to know about when writing in PHP, but yes, the discussion on what is an array and what is a list is going a tad off-topic.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem its actually very amusing with php arrays aren't really arrays so I suppose in terms relevent to this question there's no real advantage to list over array and either would work just fine.  I'm a c/c++ and c# before php person so to me they're distinctly different

Comment: @Dave: To be honest, I started as a PHP developer, but as of late, I've been tinkering with C quite a bit, and I've come to understand what a _well designed_ language actually entails. I, too, prefer C over PHP (who wouldn't), but for the OP, I'm assuming the internals aren't on the table yet, and to be frank, I'm not too _"at home"_ in C either to claim I fully understand how PHP implements arrays (HashTable with zval pointers AFAIK... but I could be wrong)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem still puts you 90% of the way ahead of everyone else though :) I'm fairly new to php only really been using it 6 years or so.  Coming from an out of order language though something that always makes me laugh is "oo php"

Comment: @Dave: :D PHP was designed by afterthought, so OOP is in some respects a natural addition to the language. Still, for all its down-sides, I've had to work with COBOL in the past, after which PHP still feels like a breath of fresh air. COBOL is the ultimate proof that a designed language isn't necessarily better.

Comment: Indeed just look at java for a poster child of horrible languages :)

Comment: @Dave: Rofl! Just read the _stuff I find to be true_ part on my stackoverflow profile, you'll see how much I loathe Java! But still, in spite of what some prominent people have said, _"The venom of Java spreadeth"_

Answer (score 8):

Neither will be simpler than using the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function's `F` code, and I'd bet $5* this would be faster than both.

```
$month = date('F');
```

For example,

```
> echo date('F');
November
```

* Coincidentally, $5 is the maximum amount of money you should spend trying to optimize this code. ;)